# Wordpress 403 Forbidden error in subdir installation

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-403

I installed Wordpress in a public_html subdir, let's say `/wordpress/`.
In the public_html root / there is no index file.
From the wordpress admin page I set the following:

```
WordPress Address (URL): https://example.org/wordpress/
Site Address (URL): https://example.org/
```

That generates the `.htaccess` in the public_html root directory (not in the subdir `/wordpress/`):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

That is not correct: it does not redirect to the right subdir, so I've modified it as:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now it seems to work: when I go to `https://example.org` I see the wordpress site without `/wordpress/` in the links.

There is an invisible problem to the humans: if I check the https header response **I get a `403 Forbidden` error** probably related to the lack of index file in the root dir.

**That blocks the search engines spiders.**

Any idea would be really appreciated,
Thank you in advance,
gil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your case same this [issue](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/330851/fix-403-error-on-wordpress-multisite-network-using-subdomains)

You can follow [this methode](https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/) from wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**

Following @Nugie suggestion, the solution is:

1. copy the `index.php` from `/wordpress/` to public_html root
2. modify the index.php in root as following:

from:

```
require __DIR__ . '/wp-blog-header.php';
```

to:

```
require __DIR__ . '/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php';
```

Now to 403 Forbidden error is gone.

Thank you @Nugie